# Performance Issues in IE8 while using JSF datatable

Tags: performance, jsf, internet-explorer-8, datatable, primefaces

In my application i am using datatable of JSF in some pages and of primefaces in some pages.
My data is quite large around 3000 rows. It works fine in IE9 and other browsers but extremely slow in IE8 and lower versions. 
first i thought it is due to some javascript issues but i think there is some problem in Datatable itself as i read this http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4698

Can you please clarify this?

My xhtml file is quite big so not pasting there. Lemme know in case you need it to answer this.

Thanks!
Tarun Madaan

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to render too large datatables, the best way would be to have a filter. If you have a large table, normally this is for exporting ie csv or excel file.

Comment: i knw this is not a good idea but i dnt hv any option. I need to show compete datatable at one go and that too without pagination or filter or something like that.. so just wanna confirm with issues in IE8.. as it works fine in IE9

Comment: If you don't need extended functions from PrimeFaces, use the plain h:dataTable it will put less load on the browser!

Comment: on same pages i don't need extended functions so used h:datatable but on some pages i need to use p:datatable but it is working in neither

Comment: btw what kind of users would understand a 3000 rows table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "normal". IE6-8 is known to have a very inefficient HTML `<table>` rendering engine. JSF or not, even with a "plain vanilla HTML" page it would stil hog on more than ~1000 cells. There's really nothing to do against other than upgrading/replacing the browser (you could if necessary recommend the clients to do so; IE8 is absolutely not "modern" anymore these days).

Your best bet is to introduce pagination. [PrimeFaces supports it out the box](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf). [Even with lazy loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf) which makes the server side part also more efficient. Google for instance does also not display all the zillion results in a single page, making it tremendously fast. Google uses also a very smart filtering algorithm on the results by a single search input field. [PrimeFaces offers table filtering as well](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf).

Comment: Thanks BalusC. i understand the fact that IE8 has a very inefficient mail. But is it documented somewhere so that we can share it with the client. As of now they are quite rigid to have support on IE 7 and 8 also.

Comment: This related answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313494/how-to-code-html-for-fast-rendering-in-ie As to your concrete problem, I really recommend to introduce pagination. Displaying 3000 records at once is very naive and primitive. You should offer filtering and pagination.