# Edge Limitation in rendering a table having more than 50,000 rows

Tags: microsoft-edge

In my web application, there is a table which has more than `50,000 rows` and is using a lot of `HTML <div>` tags. when opened in chrome or firefox table is rendered properly but Edge is only rendering a few rows of the first column and is going unresponsive.

Is this a limitation of the browser? or

Can it be fixed through browser specific coding?

please suggest anything related to this topic.

**Edit1:**

The web application is built using asp.net 3.0 web forms.

It is not working in IE11, Edge.

MSDN Forum link: [Edge Limitation in rendering a table having more than 50,000 rows](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_crash-edge_win10/edge-limitation-in-rendering-a-table-having-more/a48c30e5-4355-4d13-813b-d51839caafd3?tm=1535436780051)

Answer (score 0):

Table rendering is quite demanding on a browser, because it basically needs to render the content of *all* cells first to be able to determine how wide each column has to be. It can not safe on performance here by rendering only what is currently visible inside the viewport.

And having a table with that large amount of rows only makes it "worse" - 50,000 rows is *a lot*. (Not only for the browser, but probably for the user as well. Maybe it might make sense to offer them to filter the data somehow up front, or implement a pagination?)

You can try `table-layout:fixed` to speed up the table rendering, for a bit more details see http://www.competa.com/blog/speeding-up-rendering-of-large-html-tables/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

The browser will then apply the widths of the cells of the *first* table row as the column widths for all that follows; so usually it makes most sense to use this property in combination with explicitly specified cell widths.

Comment: The table works fine in chrome and firefox but not in edge or IE11, can you suggest anything keeping this in focus?

Comment: I did just suggest something, did I not? Have you tried that yet? Here’s a similar question with some more suggestions in the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4313494/10283047

Comment: I appreciate that you reached out to answer my question, there is no point in trying as the table is not rendered at all, IE/Edge is not slow it's not rendering the complete table, and if there are less number of rows then IE/ Edge works fantastic.

Comment: yes you suggested the pagination but my hands are tide, i cant change the application design.

Comment: Well then you might simply be out of luck, if the mere amount of rows makes IE/Edge refuse to render this _at all_ in the first place. I guess you could check if they at least create the proper DOM tree, and it is then only an issue with _displaying_ it afterwards - then you could perhaps use JavaScript to "cut out" parts of that table, and implement a pagination client-side. But if they don’t want to play ball with a table this large to begin with, then you can only either reduce the amount of data - or simply list those browsers as not compatible with your app (or the other way around.)

Comment: use the Emulation tab of the f12 dev tool to find out which Emulation Mode is being used and how it was applied. If you are developing/maintaining a asp.net v3 website then it should be using IE8 emulation. You manage legacy intranet websites backward compatibility with Enterprise site mode lists.

Comment: see the IE11 deployment guide for instructions to set up Enterprise Site Mode lists manager. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/